# How to remove object by key in Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, key, splice

I have an array like this one:

```
[{
  '0': [7]
}, {
  references: [0]
}, {
  '1': [8]
}, {
  references: [9]
}, {
  '2': [20]
}, {
  references: [50]
}]
```

I want to remove all objects containing the `reference` key. Any suggestions?

Comment: please add the object in litaral notation.

Comment: array has been transformed after `JSON.parse(a)`

Answer (score 4):

not pop or splice, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var a = [
           { 0:[7]}, 
           { references:[0]}, 
           { 1:[8]}, 
           {references:[9]}, 
           { 2:[20]}, 
           { references:[50]}
];

var filteredA = a.filter(function(item){ return !('references' in item) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object in literal notation. Then you can find the key by `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
var a = [
           { 0:[7]}, 
           { references:[0]}, 
           { 1:[8]}, 
           {references:[9]}, 
           { 2:[20]}, 
           { references:[50]}
]
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) { 
    if(a[i].hasOwnProperty('references')) { 
        a.splice(i, 1);
    } 
}
```